# Datex-II: malformed OpenLR?

Tags: data-format

My reading of Datex-II (as of version 2.3) is that OpenLR locations are specified roughly like this for linear features:

```
…
<SituationRecord …>
  <!-- description of the event here -->
  <groupOfLocations xsi:type="Linear">
    <linearExtension>
      <openlrExtendedLinear>
        <firstDirection>
          <!-- location reference points here -->
        </firstDirection>
        <oppositeDirection> <!-- where applicable -->
          <!-- location reference points here -->
        </oppositeDirection>
      </openlrExtendedLinear>
      …
```

Indeed I have seen Datex-II situation publications structured like this, and JAXB parses them nicely into the class scheme I generated from the XSD.

Now I am seeing feeds which have `<openlrLineLocationReference>` instead of `<firstDirection>`. Since the XSD appears to make no mention of that, JAXB ignores the `<openlrLineLocationReference>` element and the `OpenlrExtendedLinear` instance it returns contains no data (it has two members, `firstDirection` and `oppositeDirection`, both of which are null).

Is that incorrect data, or have I missed some part of the specs? (I see Datex-II 3.0 is out by now, but parsing the XSDs with JAXB failed—has this part of OpenLR been updated?)